# FileFilter problema con el if-else

Tags: java

Tengo un problema, supongo que muchas horas programando pero no lo sé ver,
y seguro que es lo más tonto del mundo.

Tengo el siguiente programa:

```
FileFilter directoryFilter = new FileFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File file) {
                return file.isDirectory();
            }
                };
        File[] files = miDir.listFiles(directoryFilter);
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.print("directorio:");
                        } else{
                                System.out.print("   archivo:");
                                 // Mostrar archivos ocultos  
                                 int total=0;
                                 File[] archivosYCarpetasInternos = miDir.listFiles();
                                 for (File archivoOCarpeta : archivosYCarpetasInternos) {//si esta oculto..
                                 if (archivoOCarpeta.isHidden()) { 
                                 // System.out.println(ficheros[x].getName()); Por si queremos mostrar cuales son... 
                                 //Aquí lo que hacemos..
                                  total ++; }      
                                    }System.out.println("Número de fitxers ocults :"+total); 

            }
            System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());}
```

Lo que quiero conseguir es con el FileFilter dividir mi programa en dos partes por una parte directorios y por otra archivos.

Por ahora la parte de archivos dentro del if perfecto por que me muestra los 4 archivos que hay, pero quiero hacer lo mismo con el else, que me muestre los archivos.

Imagino que el error está ahí pero no sé verlo.

gracias!.

Comment: Al usar `isHidden()` en: `if (archivoOCarpeta.isHidden()) {  total ++; }`     te contará sólo los archivos ocultos. ¿Es eso lo que quieres, saber cuántos archivos ocultos hay en la carpeta? Mira este ejemplo: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/Countfilesinadirectoryincludingfilesinallsubdirectories.htm

Comment: Quiero saber tanto en carpeta como en directorios. Pero separado. 

Es decir:

Archivos ocultos : (Resultado)
Directorios ocultos: ( Resultado )

Comment: Pero no tengo el problema con el conteo.. si te fijes en archivos ya lo he echo.. es simplemente que me muestra ambas cosas a la vez. Pero no lo consigo...

Comment: _es simplemente que me muestra ambas cosas a la vez. Pero no lo consigo_ No entiendo... ¿podrías precisar mejor lo que quieres? ¿Que te muestre un solo mensaje con el total de directorios y archivos? ¿Que te muestre dos mensajes, uno con los directorios y otro con los archivos ocultos? ¿Qué te muestra actualmente el programa?

Comment: Intento explicarlo con palabras.

El programa tiene que mostrarme dos cosas por una parte directorio y por otra archivos. Y luego dentro de Directorio los directorios ocultos y dentro de archivos los archivos ocultos.

Esto usando un filtro para separar una cosa de la otra.

Comment: Ahora mismo el programa me muestra la parte del If, es decir la parte de los directorios perfectamente pero la parte de el else ( archivos no me la lee.. )

Comment: He publicado una respuesta. No estabas contando tus directorios. De todos modos el planteamiento de tu pregunta es confuso, no se comprende bien lo que quieres. A  veces no sé si llamas directorios a los archivos o viceversa cuando te explicas. Si la respuesta no te funciona te recomiendo que releas la pregunta y trates de explicar con más claridad lo que quieres hacer, lo que te funciona y lo que no.

Comment: Ya esta solucionado con tu ayuda me ha ido genial!
Muchas gracias!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto debería funcionar. No estabas contando los directorios:

```
        for (File file : files) {
            int totalDir=0;
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                totalDir ++;
                System.out.print("directorio:");
            } else {
                System.out.print("   archivo:");
                // Mostrar archivos ocultos  
                int total=0;
                File[] archivosYCarpetasInternos = miDir.listFiles();
                for (File archivoOCarpeta : archivosYCarpetasInternos){
                //si esta oculto..
                     if (archivoOCarpeta.isHidden()) { 
                         // System.out.println(ficheros[x].getName()); Por si queremos mostrar cuales son... 
                         //Aquí lo que hacemos..
                         total ++; 
                      }      
                 }
System.out.println("Número de directorios :"+totalDir); 
System.out.println("Número de fitxers ocults :"+total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Porque no pruebas esto:

```
 for (File file : files) {

          if(file .getPath().equalsIgnoreCase("ruta de directorio")){
  //codigo restante
}
     if(file .getPath().equalsIgnoreCase("ruta de archivos")){
  //codigo restante
}
}}
```

Establezco un if dentro del bucle uno para directorios y otro para archivos

Comment: No es lo que necesito.. Lo acabo de comentar lo que no consigo es esto:

Filtro para separar directorios de Archivos.

Directorios :
         Directorios ocultos:

Archivos:
         Archivos ocultos:

Lo que no consigo es hacer el programa con el filtro. No necesito la parte de buscar los archivos ocultos eso ya lo tengo..

Sino necesito conseguir el filtro .. T_T